# what is wrong about the I420 render from ffmpeg?

Tags: opengl, ffmpeg, glfw

I use glfw render YUV from ffmpeg;the Y is ok(only use data Y ,and frag texture2D Y is ok ,the color is Grayscale).but when I add U,V ;the display show pink and green; I try to change frag shader or the imgtexture ,there have no use .

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 544;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 960;
const int len = 544 * 960 * 3/2;
BYTE YUVdata [len];//
BYTE Ydata [544 * 960];//
BYTE Udata [272 * 480];//
BYTE Vdata [272 * 480];//
unsigned int VBO = 0;
unsigned int VAO = 0;
unsigned int EBO = 0;
unsigned int texturePIC = 0;
int shaderProgram = 0;

GLuint texIndexarray[3];
GLuint texUniformY = 99;
GLuint texUniformU = 99;
GLuint texUniformV = 99;

void LoadPicture()
{


    glGenTextures(3, texIndexarray);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[0]);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[1]);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[2]);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);

    texUniformY = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "dataY");//2
    texUniformU = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "dataU");//0
    texUniformV = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "dataV");//1

    
    FILE* fp = fopen("./output544_960.yuv","rb+");//I420
    int returns  =fread(YUVdata,1,len,fp);
    int w = 544;
    int h = 960;
    int ysize = w*h;
    int uvsize = w * h / 4;

    void* uptr = &YUVdata[ysize];
    void* vptr = &YUVdata[ysize * 5 / 4];

    memcpy(Ydata,YUVdata,ysize);
    memcpy(Udata, uptr,uvsize);
    memcpy(Vdata, vptr,uvsize);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[0]);
    
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 , GL_RED, w, h ,0, GL_RED,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE ,Ydata);
    glUniform1i(texUniformY, texIndexarray[0]);               


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, w/2, h/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Udata );

    glUniform1i(texUniformU, texIndexarray[1]);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIndexarray[2]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, w/2, h/2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Vdata);
    glUniform1i(texUniformV, texIndexarray[2]);

}


void render()
{
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,4);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void initmodule()
{
    
    float vertexs[] = {
        
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,   
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,   
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f    
    
    
    };
    
    unsigned int indexs[] = {
        0,1,3,
        1,2,3,
    };

    
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertexs), vertexs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    
    glGenBuffers(1,&EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(indexs),indexs,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    LoadPicture();

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,5*sizeof(float),(void*)0);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

    
    glBindVertexArray(0);



}

void initshader(const char* verpath,const char* fragpath)
{
    
    std::string VerCode("");
    std::string fregCode("");
    
    std::ifstream  vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream  fShaderFile;

    vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    try
    {
        vShaderFile.open(verpath);
        fShaderFile.open(fragpath);

        std::stringstream vsstream, fsstream;
        vsstream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fsstream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
        VerCode = vsstream.str();
        fregCode = fsstream.str();
    
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "read file error" << std::endl;
    }

    const char* vshader = VerCode.c_str();
    const char* fshader = fregCode.c_str();

    
    unsigned int vertexID = 0, fragID = 0;
    char infoLog[512];
    int  successflag = 0;
    vertexID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexID,1,&vshader,NULL );
    glCompileShader(vertexID);
    
    glGetShaderiv(vertexID,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&successflag);
    if (!successflag)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID,512,NULL,infoLog);
        std::string errstr(infoLog);
        std::cout << "v shader err"<<infoLog;
    }
    //frag
    fragID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragID, 1, &fshader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragID);
    
    glGetShaderiv(fragID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &successflag);
    if (!successflag)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragID, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::string errstr(infoLog);
        std::cout << "f shader err"<<infoLog;
    }
    
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,vertexID);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,fragID);

    glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "aPos");
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "texCoord");

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram,GL_LINK_STATUS,&successflag);
    if (!successflag)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::string errstr(infoLog);
        std::cout << "link error";
    }

    
    glDeleteShader(vertexID);
    glDeleteShader(fragID);
}
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main()
{
    
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(544, 960, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("");
        
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("");
        return -1;
    }
    initshader("vertexShader.glsl", "fragmentShader.glsl");//
    initmodule();


    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        
        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        render();
    
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the Y data ,and run the code is ok;the color is gray;but when I add the U ,the color is Light green；and when i add the V is pink and green;

```
    #version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D dataY;
uniform sampler2D dataU;
uniform sampler2D dataV;
vec3 yuv;
vec3 rgb;
void main()
{


   yuv.x = texture2D(dataY, TexCoord).r-0.0625;
   yuv.y = texture2D(dataU, TexCoord).r-0.5;
   yuv.z = texture2D(dataV, TexCoord).r-0.5;

   rgb = mat3(1,              1,      1,     
            0,       -0.18732, 1.8556,    
            1.57481, -0.46813,      0) * yuv;   
    FragColor = vec4(rgb.x, rgb.y,rgb.z,1); 
};
```

Comment: Did you already try no-matrix version in your shader? If so, what was the result?

Comment: yes ,I used different formats of fragment code； but the color  not right